# Coldfusion Regex to convert a URL to lowercase

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am trying to take convert urls in a block of html to ensure they are lowercase.
Some of the links are a mix of uppercase and lowercase and they need to be converted to just lowercase.
It would be impossible to run round the site and redo every link so was looking to use a Regex when outputting the text.

```
<p>Hello world <a href="http://www.somelink.com/HOME">Some link</a>.</p>
```

Needs to be converted to:

```
 <p>Hello world <a href="http://www.somelink.com/home">Some link</a>.</p>
```

Using a ColdFusion Regex such as below (although this doesn't work):

```
<cfset content = Rereplace(content,'(http[*])','\L\1','All')>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It is difficult to tell - are the URLS being output using ColdFusion? If so, Evik's answer below is the way to go. If you have an existing chunk of HTML, that already has the links in it that you need to fix, then a different solution is needed.

Comment: I do not think that there is a regEx that would work in ColdFusion. You could use `REFind()` with the following regex `http[^"\']*` and specify to return subexpressions to get all the instances of links in a block of HTM. You can then loop over the results of the `REFind()` and use `mid()` and `lcase()` to change the text to lower case.

Comment: @Scott - I am not a regex guru, but I think your expression should work with ReReplace, something like `'(http://[^"]+)`. It seemed to in my (brief) tests.

Comment: @Leigh I tried using `REReplace()` without much success. I forgot about `REMatch()` which I used below and seems to work well. I will play with `REReplace()` some more to see if I can get it working.

Comment: Whatever you come up with for rematch or rereplace, I'm pretty sure I can provide valid HTML that will break it. ;)

Comment: Then the RegEx can be tweaked ;-). Using a client side fix is a neat idea. A server side solution also has the advantage of being used to actually update the data he has in the database rather than just mask the problem.

Comment: This can be done server-side with jSoup too - I just always find myself using jSoup and since it seemed like more of a one-off fix I decided to do jQuery this time, so there's no messing with JARs.

Answer (score 4):

I think I would use the lower case function, lCase().

Put your URL into a variable, if it's not already:

```
<cfset MyVar = "http://www.ThisSite.com">
```

Force it to lower case here:

```
<cfset MyVar = lCase(MyVar)>
```

Or here:

```
<cfoutput>
<a href="#lCase(MyVar)#">Some Link</a>
</cfoutput>
```

UPDATE: Actually, I see that what you are actually asking is how to generate your entire HTML page (or a big portion) and then go back through it, find all of the links, and then lower their cases. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hiya, yeah the blocks of HTML are already in the db so would need to be a regex to run through the block of html to identify any links and convert them to lowercase on output.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have the HTML stored in a database, there is a bit more work that needs to be done than just using `lcase()`. I would wrap the functionality into a function that can be easily reused. Check out this code for an example.

```
content = '<p>Hello world <a href="http://www.somelink.com/HOME">Some link</a>.</p>
            <p>Hello world <a href="http://www.somelink.com/TEST">Some link</a>.</p>
            <p>Hello world <a href=''http://www.somelink.com/BLARG''>Some link</a>.</p>';
writeDump( content );
writeDump( fixLinks( content ) );

function fixLinks( str ){
    var links = REMatch( 'http[^"'']*', str  );
    for( var link in links ){
        str = replace( str, link, lcase( link ), "ALL" );
    }
    return str;
}
```

This has only been tested in CF9 & CF10.

Using `REMatch()` you get an array of matches. You then simply loop over that array and use `replace()` with `lcase()` to make the links lowercase.

And...based on Leigh's suggestion, here is a solution in one line of code using `REReplace()`

```
REReplace( content, '(http[^"'']*)', '\L\1', 'all' )
```

Comment: Ok, so here's two examples of where this breaks...

`content = '<script src="http://somewhere.com/jqGrid.js"></script>
 ...
 <p>Make sure you go to <b>https</b>://google.com and NOT <b>http</b>://google.com OK?'`

and there's plenty more...

Comment: He did not state that `script` tags needed to be replaced, only `a`.  Once again, if those needs arise...it can be tweaked.

Comment: Exactly; the code you posted doesn't differentiate. The OP has an arbitrary block of html - we don't know what tags it does/doesn't contain, or even if it's actually valid HTML or provided by clients. A HTML parser can target just the hrefs (or whatever needs changing) with guaranteed success. The best a simple CF regex can do is probably `(<a(?=\s)[^>]*\shref\s*=\s*)([^'"\s]+|'[^']+|"[^"]+])` and replace `\1\L\2` which might be good enough, or might not be good enough because maybe it needs to check for img/src or data attributes or whatever.

Comment: He did not ask for an HTML parser,m he asked for help with a regex, which I offered.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your help. I have been trying this and realised that some of the links are relative and not always absolute. Is there a way of altering this to search for href instead of http?

Comment: You just proved Peter's point :D. I will try to tweak the RegEx...or you could try to utilize what he suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Use a HTML parser to parse HTML, not regex.

Here's how you can do it with jQuery:

```
<!doctype html>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<cfsavecontent variable="HtmlCode">
    <p>Hello world <a href="http://www.somelink.com/HOME">Some link</a>.</p>
</cfsavecontent>

<pre></pre>

<script>
    var HtmlCode = "<cfoutput>#JsStringFormat(HtmlCode)#</cfoutput>";

    HtmlCode = jQuery('a[href]',HtmlCode).each( lowercaseHref ).end().html();

    function lowercaseHref(index,item)
    {
        var $item = jQuery(item);

    // prevent non-links from being changed
    // (alternatively, can check for specific domain, etc)
        if ( $item.attr('href').startsWith('#') )
        return

        $item.attr( 'href' , $item.attr('href').toLowerCase() );
    }

    jQuery('pre').text(HtmlCode);
</script>
```

This works for `href` attributes on `a` tags, but can of course be updated for other things.

It will ignore in-page links like `<a href="#SomeId">` but not stuff like `<a href="/HOME/#SomeId">` - if that's an issue you'd need to update the function to exclude page fragment part (e.g. split on `#` then rejoin, or whatever). Same goes if you might have case-sensitive querystrings.

And of course the above is just jQuery because I felt like it - you could also use a server-side HTML parser, like [jSoup](http://jsoup.org) to achieve this.